# Why wp_query return 1 row if i have 3 row pass in it

Tags: wp-query

I have this query to return the post

```
$sitens = new wp_query( array ( 'post_type' => 'post' , 'post__in' => array($post_id) ) ); 
if ( $sitens->have_posts() ) : while ( $sitens->have_posts() ) : $sitens->the_post();
$message .= '<tr width="50%" style="float:right;width:50%;text-align:center;margin-top:30px;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;padding-bottom: 20px;">
<td style="text-align: center;margin-right: auto;display: block;margin-left: auto;">
<div style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-top: 15px;direction:rtl;text-decoration: none;height: 50px;">
    <a href="'.get_permalink($sitens->post->ID).'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <span class="post_title_" style="font:bold 20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important; color:#359bcf">'.get_the_title( $sitens->post->ID ).'</span>
    </a>
    </div>      
    <a href="'.get_permalink($sitens->post->ID).'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
    '.get_the_post_thumbnail($sitens->post->ID, 'home-grid').'
    </a>    
    </td>
  </tr>';
endwhile; endif;
```

But the error is when `$post_id` have 3 id like `('444','3','22')`, it must return me 3 post, But its return me 1 post

Why?

Comment: If `$post_id` is already an array, don't wrap it in another - just use `'post__in' => $post_id`

Comment: the `$post_id` value is like `444,3,22` how can us it in `post__in`

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_parse_id_list` to split a comma separated string of IDs into an array:

```
'post__in' => wp_parse_id_list( $post_id ),
```